# Copy lambda which captures moved object

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Why this [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/Pq1KjYbb5) does not compile?

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> uniq_ptr(new int{6});
    auto foo_a = [&uniq_ptr]{std::cout << *uniq_ptr << std::endl;};
    std::bind(foo_a)(); //works
    foo_a();            //works

    auto foo_b = [up = std::move(uniq_ptr)]()mutable{*up = 5; std::cout << *up << std::endl;};
    foo_b();           //works;

#ifdef CHOOSE_1
    auto foo_b1 = foo_b; //Surprised!  I think `up` could be copied.But the compiler complains: Error: use of deleted function 'main()::<lambda()>::<lambda>(const main()::<lambda()>&)'
#else
    std::bind(foo_b);    //Same error!
#endif
}
```

For `auto foo_b = [up = std::move(uniq_ptr)]()mutable{//...}`, I think `foo_b` could be copied since `up` a rvalue, and it could be copied by move constructor.

Comment: You can't copy via the move constructor, you can only move

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[up = std::move(uniq_ptr)]` just moves `uniq_ptr` to a member variable of the lambda.

`std::bind` will internally construct a copy of `foo_b`. Since `foo_b` contains a `unique_ptr` that is not copyable, `foo_b` itself is not copyable.

You should move `foo_b` into `std::bind`:

```
std::bind(std::move(foo_b));
```

Or move `foo_b` into `foo_b1`

```
auto foo_b1 = std::move(foo_b);
```

Comment: *Since foo_b contains a unique_ptr that is not copyable, foo_b itself is not copyable.* I know that `std::unique` is not copyable, whereas it could be moved. What confuses me is that `up` is `std::move(uniq_ptr)`, it could be copied by move constructor. Then I think `foo_b` could be copied.

Comment: `up` is not an rvalue, it's an lvalue.

Comment: Yes, updatad. What confuses me is that `up` is `std::move(uniq_ptr)`, it could be copied by move constructor. Then I think `foo_b` could be copied.Where am I wrong?

Comment: `foo_b` can be copied by the move constructor, but `auto foo_b1 = foo_b` will invoke the copy constructor *not* move constructor, you need to use `std::move` to cast it to an rvalue to invoke the move constructor.  Same goes for `std::bind(foo_b)`.

Comment: So if an object whose type is `Class Demo` would be copied by copy constructor, then every member variable of `Class Demo` needs to be copied by the copy constructor itself. It's impossible that some member varariables use its copy constructor, and the others calls the move constructor. Am I right?

Comment: @John You're right: the automatically generated copy constructor uses the copy constructor of every member and every base of the type. The automatically generated move constructor though can fall back to the copy constructor... In `[up = std::move(uniq_ptr)]` `up` has type `std::unique_ptr<int>` btw; it doesn't store the value as `std::unique_ptr<int> &&` and even if it did, references are non-copyable.